# member function declared in class

Tags: c++, int, return

compiler shows error :

> src/face_svl_cnt_htmllogger.cpp:660:33: error: no 'int
>   FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger::param()' member function declared in class
>   'FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger'

part of class "FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger"

```
int FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger::param(){

return s;

}
```

please give me a solution to solve it , thanks!!

Comment: The error message tells you _exactly_ what the problem is.

Comment: It seems that you've forgot to *declare* the function inside your `FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger` class.  But without seeing the code, we can't really tell you more.

Comment: Would you mind showing how you declared that member function actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message provided by the compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is. The function `param()` has not been declared in class `FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger`. In order for a function the be defined outside of a class you also have to *declare* it inside of the class definition.

```
class FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger
{
public:
    int param();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, my error has been solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your source file and your header file.

Make sure there are no typos in the source file.

Make sure that 
int param()
or
virtual int param()

is declared in class FaceSvlCntHtmlLogger in the header file.

If the class is a child class, and param() is a public member function, then insure that int param is also declared on the parent class.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget the " ; " at the end of the function declaration in the class :

```
public:
    int param();
```

If it isn't that, please give more information about the class and your c++ file

Comment: _"Don't forget the " ; " at the end of the function declaration in the class"_ Uhmm, what please?!? Where's any evidence from the OP that could be a reason for this error? (and unlikely it will result in this particular one). Please don't just guess, and post as an answer.